# Unable to receive emails from PHP website hosted on Azure

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid

I have moved a website from simple hosting to Azure Cloud, but now my emails are not being sent. I have installed SendGrid and saved the username and password. Then I edited my contact.php file. Code of contact.php is:

```
 <?php
 $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
 $user = 'username that I saved';
 $pass = 'password that I created';

 $params = array(
      'api_user' => $user,
      'api_key' => $pass,
      'to' => 'mymailaddress@mail.com',
      'subject' => 'testing from curl',
      'html' => 'testing body',
      'text' => 'testing body',
      'from' => 'anna@contoso.com',
   );

 $request = $url.'api/mail.send.json';

 // Generate curl request
 $session = curl_init($request);

 // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

 // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

 // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // obtain response
 $response = curl_exec($session);
 curl_close($session);

 // print everything out
 print_r($response);
?>
```

I saved it and accessed it via my browser but nothing showed up. I check my email inbox(Spam Also) but nothing was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response, but I fixed that by using PHPMailer. I downloaded it and uploaded it. In that folder I created a file with this code and it worked like a chram.

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'; 
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                          // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.sendgrid.net';             // Specify main/backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                           // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';    // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';    // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                        // Enable TLS/SSL encryption



$mail->From = "Email of Person";
$mail->FromName = "Name of Person";
$mail->addAddress('myaddress@mail.com', 'Support');     // Add a recipient

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                              // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Subject is XYZ';
$mail->Body    =  "A message was sent to you from your website.<br> Email:".$from."<br>Name: ".$name."<br>Message: ".$message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message sent successfully';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find here the documentation...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-sendgrid-php-how-to-send-email

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I already read that blog but it didn't work for me. I found another solution.
Anyways, Thanks a ton @Larry Lurex.

Comment: Can you post  print_r($response); ?

Comment: That's the issue, I wasn't getting any response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `x-smtpapi` in $params array(), create a JSON array with to and category element.

```
$json_string = array(
      "to" => array(
    "mymailaddress@mail.com"
      ),
      "category" => "subscription"
    );
```

Add this in $param array().

```
$params = array(
      'api_user' => $user,
      'api_key' => $pass,
      'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string),
      'to' => 'mymailaddress@mail.com',
      'subject' => 'testing from curl',
      'html' => 'testing body',
      'text' => 'testing body',
      'from' => 'anna@contoso.com',
   );
```

Comment: Thanks but another solution worked for me. Thanks a ton @Mohd Asim